# Всё ли в порядке с пунктуацией?

Tags: пунктуация, и

Её количество известно каждому и не может быть намеренно завышено, что сложно контролировать и подделать.

Comment: Вопрос: количество подделать — это как?

Comment: Если сложно контролировать,  значит, легко подделать, и наоборот.

Comment: Количество подделать можно, сто пудов.

Comment: Если процесс сложный, то он не достаточно прозрачен. Значит легко подсунуть брак, а украсть еще легче.

Answer (score 1):

Нет запятой – однородные сказуемые. Но конец фразы совершенно невнятный, надо бы переделать. Что хотим сказать?

Comment: Речь о вермишели, допустим. Сложно контролировать подделывание объемов производства, потому что уже сегодня все знают сколько ее будет завтра. Да, конец конченый какой-то. После запятой я напишу: это супер сложная задача. бла бла бла..а то что есть уберу.

Comment: Тогда у вас пропущено "потому". Не "что сложно контролировать и подделать", а "ПОТОМУ что сложно контролировать и подделать".

Comment: да да. верно. я изменил уже.

Comment: @Андрей, если у вас есть приемлемая формулировка -  пожалуйста, измените вопрос, чтобы не порождать ненужную дискуссию.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, поскольку "и" связывает однородные члены предложения (сказуемые при общем подлежащем).

Comment: спс спс спс спс 12